# Dual booting windows 8.1 and fedora 19

Tags: windows

I am trying to dual boot windows 8.1 and fedora 19. I am in UEFI mode and using USB. I installed windows 8.1 and left some free unpartitioned space.. Now when fedora installation is going on I am stuck at installation source. The auto detect media option detects sda1 but verification says bad image.

Comment: What is your question? How to prevent the verification to say bad image? This is a bit too broad with this little information.

Comment: I am not able to start installation as i can't select installation source... So, i think it would be 'How to prevent the verification to say bad image'